# UICustomTableViewCell - Set label in middle vertically

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitableview

I have a custom cell that I have created. In the tableviewController I set the height of the cell to 70 like this:

```
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

return 70;

}
```

So I figured that in my custom cell I would do this:

```
- (void)awakeFromNib {
    [openLabel setFrame:CGRectMake(174, 35, 136, 35)];
}
```

But this didn't work I set it near the bottom of the cell I am very confused, why this is happening?

I have made this label in the interface builder if that matters

Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: If you are using constraints or auto layout, then setting the frame of the label won't do anything.

Comment: @DanielT. I am not using auto layout or constraints

Comment: So you turned off auto layout explicitly?

Answer (score 1):

If your label is 35pts tall, and you set `y` to 35, then the top corner of the label will be at `y`, leaving the label to take up the rest of the cell.

Use `CGRectMake(174, (35 - (35/2)), 136, 35)`, since you want the halfway point of the height to be center.

Or more generally, `(midpoint - (height of element / 2))`.

Comment: this doesn't put it in the middel

Comment: you have it backwards it should be `CGRectMake(174, (35 - (35/2)), 136, 35)]`

Comment: derp, apparently I forgot how `CGRectMake` accepts arguments. :)